# Windows 11 wsl2 + wslg virtualization issues

Tags: windows, proxmox

I am trying to get VM Windows 11 (Enterprise evaluation) to work with wsl2+wslg enabled on Proxmox and on Ubuntu20.04/qemu/kvm server with no success.
The server Windows Server 2022 (standard) VM with Hyper-V (nested) works with no issues on Proxmox.

My Windows 11 VM works for the first 6-8 hours (initial start with the disconnected remote session) and then freezes (cpu utilization 100%). But if I run some Youtube video (like some live radio station) it works but only if the webpage is kept open and not minimized (with the disconnected remote session) . Or it works if I actively work in the open session. As soon as I disconnect (after those initial 6-8 hours) it freezes every time right away. What a weird behavior.
All sleep modes disabled via Power Options and Ultimate Performance is selected.

All VM configurations for Windows 11 and for working Windows Server 2022 are similar.

Windows 11 without wsl2+wslg enabled doesn't freeze.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit (detailed information):

```
CPU:  AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
MB:   B550I AORUS PRO AX
RAM: 32GB
Proxmox 7.1-8 kernel: 5.15.7-1-pve

Guest: Windows 11 Enterprise (evaluation)
```

Proxmox vm config:

```
agent: 1
args: -cpu 'EPYC,hv-passthrough,+svm'
balloon: 0
bios: ovmf
boot: order=virtio0;ide2;sata0;net0
cores: 4
cpu: EPYC
efidisk0: zfsa:vm-108-disk-1,efitype=4m,size=1M
ide2: zfsa_mp:iso/win11-ent-eval.iso,media=cdrom
machine: pc-q35-6.1
memory: 4096
meta: creation-qemu=6.1.0,ctime=1640567738
name: win11-vm-2
net0: virtio=1A:AE:7E:5B:81:59,bridge=vmbr0,firewall=1
numa: 0
onboot: 1
ostype: win11
sata0: zfsa_mp:iso/virtio-win-0.1.208.iso,media=cdrom,size=543390K
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=fe7771a9-6316-4525-ad7b-9090441a855d
sockets: 1
tpmstate0: zfsa:vm-108-disk-2,size=4M,version=v2.0
vga: virtio
virtio0: zfsa:vm-108-disk-0,discard=on,size=64G
vmgenid: 02dcaea7-5a30-47c9-9aaf-34af19d4fd3e
```

In this configuration I am using EPYC (emulated cpu) but with the 'host' it works (or rather doesn't) the same way. But, again, Hyper-V server (Windows 2022) nested works with no issues. There is something about wsl2/wslg nested that causes these issues.

Comment: i lost myself in the text, can you maybe tell what is the main host and afterwards telling ehat is how virtualized?

Comment: I added the host info to my post.

Comment: Have you reported this issue to the WSL2 GitHub project?

Comment: No, not yet....